# Issues mounting a shared folder in virtualbox

Tags: macos, debian, virtualbox, shared-directory

I'm trying to create a shared folder between MacOS (Host) and Debian (Guest) in virtualbox. I've completed the steps of installing guest additions, creating a shared folder called "share" and a folder in debian called "sf", but when I try to run

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf share ~/sf
```

I get the error

```
mount: realpath /Users/USERNAME/sf: No such file or directory
```

I'm under the impression the second path is meant to be the directory in Debian. This also happens when I remove the ~/.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to run this command from your OSX shell. Is that possibly the case?

If yes, switch to your shell on the Debian guest. Also make sure the directory `~/sf` actually does exist before you run the `mount` command.

Hope this helps.